# Where to create the FormGroup in an Angular component?

Tags: angular, angular15, angular-dynamic-forms

I have angular 15 application containing `Project`s and `Todo`s. and wondering where in my project component to create the following formgroup:

```
public todoForm: UntypedFormGroup = this.builder.group({});
```

The full context is :

```
/**
 * Project component.
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'project',
  templateUrl: './project.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project.component.scss']
})
export class ProjectComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public currentProject?: Project;
  public currentTodo?: Todo;
  // ? here
  public loading = false;   
  public currentLang: string = "";    
  private onDestroy = new ReplaySubject(1);

  constructor(
    private storage: LocalStorageService,
    private translateService: TranslateService,
    private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private todoService: TodoService,
    private projectService: ProjectService,
    public todoForm: UntypedFormGroup,          // PROBLEM
    public settingsService: SettingsService,
    private builder: UntypedFormBuilder,
    private notyfService: NotyfService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
  ) {
    this.todoForm = this.builder.group({});    // PROBLEM
  }
```

I also read this solution.

It was initially like this (out of constructor)

```
export class ProjectComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public currentProject?: Project;
  public currentTodo?: Todo;
  public todoForm: UntypedFormGroup = this.builder.group({});
```

however in that case it complained the **builder** is null...

What to do? I read also [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61338248/961631), but it is not clear where should I create that element.

[image]

If I do initialization in constructor without "?" the compiler is happy; however it will throw error in runtime:

> core.mjs:9095 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(ProjectModule)[FormGroup -> FormGroup -> FormGroup -> FormGroup]: NullInjectorError: No provider for FormGroup!

**PS.**

As the html of project component is like this

```
<div class="col" [formGroup]="todoForm">
  <kendo-tabstrip tabPosition="right" [keepTabContent]="true" #tabstrip>
  </kendo-tabstrip>
</div>
```

I added the following

```
export class ProjectComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild('tabstrip') public tabstrip: TabStripComponent | undefined;
```

I have no more the error null error, but now it throws another error

> app-routing.module.ts:18 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk Client_app_project_project_module_ts failed.
> (missing: http://localhost:4200/Client_app_project_project_module_ts.js)
> ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk Client_app_project_project_module_ts failed.
> (missing: http://localhost:4200/Client_app_project_project_module_ts.js)
> at **webpack_require**.f.j (jsonp chunk loading:27:1)
> at ensure chunk:6:1

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize the `formGroup` in the constructor but usually you initialize it in `ngOnInit`. The problem is, that you expect the `formGroup` as a parameter to your constructor, which obviously does not work. Do it like this:

```js
/**
 * Project component.
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'project',
  templateUrl: './project.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project.component.scss']
})
export class ProjectComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public currentProject?: Project;
  public currentTodo?: Todo;

  public loading = false;

  //public errors: ErrorEntry[] = [];
  public currentLang: string = "";

  private onDestroy = new ReplaySubject(1);

  //We need to declare our variable here
  public todoForm: UntypedFormGroup;

  constructor(
    private storage: LocalStorageService,
    private translateService: TranslateService,
    private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private todoService: TodoService,
    private projectService: ProjectService,
    public settingsService: SettingsService,
    private builder: UntypedFormBuilder,
    private notyfService: NotyfService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
  ) {
    this.todoForm = this.builder.group({})
  }
```

Comment: here I should initialize the non-nullable field...

Comment: Yep sorry. missed the `?`

Comment: that will break the HTML logic, where that is not nullable

Comment: If you do the initialization inside the constructor can you remove the `?` without typescript complaining?

Comment: @in the constructor without "?" the compiler is happy; however it will throw error in runtime:  core.mjs:9095 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(ProjectModule)[FormGroup -> FormGroup -> FormGroup -> FormGroup]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for FormGroup!

Comment: I edited my answer to make it more clear. You can't have the declaration of the variable in the constructor, but the initialization can be in the constructor.

Comment: added in PS more details about